# Passwordless ssh issues in google cloud

Tags: ssh, centos6

Have setup 2 Centos instance, created the public and private keys, but when trying to ssh from one machine to another getting following error message "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)". Following are steps i followed :-

1. **ssh-keygen -t rsa**
2. **cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys**
3. **chmod 755 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys**
4. **Shut down the firewall, and checked sshd service status it is
   running.**
5. **Copied the public key one machine to authorized keys file of another
   and vice versa.**
6. **When trying to ssh from one machine to another getting the above
   said error.**

Please help resolve the issue, is process different for google cloud?

Comment: What does the sshd log say about the attempts?

Comment: I have tried to follow your steps, and I do not get any error. There is something wrong with your steps, `755` is wrong and should have been `600` or `644`. But that doesn't explain the error message you are getting. There is likely useful information in `/var/log/auth.log`.

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshooting SSH auth**

1. Show us your `config` file if you use one or show us your ssh command
2. Use `-vvv` option and look where it went wrong
3. Monitor your target machine's secure log - `tail -f /var/log/secure`

It could be as simple as permission issue but it should show on the logs.